# Android application crashes, here's the code

Tags: java, android, xml

I did everything that was needed like registering in the manifest. But the application crasher at launch with the usual android error. Appreciating any help.

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Tabs extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.R.layout.tabs);
        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(com.example.R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Stop Watch");
        th.addTab(specs);


        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(com.example.R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Tab 2");
        th.addTab(specs);

        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(com.example.R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Add a Tab");
        th.addTab(specs);
    }


}
```

Here is the XML part. Code for xml starts here. please check this out too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help.

Comment: what is com.example.R.layout.tabs ??? why not R.layout.tabs///

Comment: Post logcat errors so we can understand your problems easily.

Comment: What error message does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Change

```
 TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

to

```
 TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(com.example.R.id.tabhost);
```

or

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

to

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: it is kind of another question but earlier i did not have to add the "com.blah" part with "r.blah" part. but now it is underlined as an error. Appreciated your above answer btw

Comment: You need to import `your.package.name.R` then you can directly use `R.id.tabhost`

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
```

Change this @ all com.example.R to R. something either it is R.id or R.layout
hope this will hepls you